# How to get multilevel aggregated result from map using Java8 stream and groupBy?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to get aggregated output out of my map by using stream grouping features.
basically I want multilevel groupby using stream. I have a map with some data and want map as output with aggregated data.

Overall it has cityArea with various areaPin inside it. Each areaPin has two section: 1 and 2. I want to sum corresponding count by section and want that aggregation data per cityId. Please refer below classes. So it is like I have aggregated information by cityId+areaPin and I want aggregated information by cityId out of it.

CityArea:

```
public class CityArea {
String cityId;
String areaPin;
public String getCityId() {
    return cityId;
}
public void setCityId(String cityId) {
    this.cityId = cityId;
}
public String getAreaPin() {
    return areaPin;
}
public void setAreaPin(String areaPin) {
    this.areaPin = areaPin;
}
public CityArea(String cityId, String areaPin) {
    super();
    this.cityId = cityId;
    this.areaPin = areaPin;
}
public CityArea() {
    super();
}
```

}

ResourceCount:

```
public class ResourceCount {

Integer streetLightCount;
Integer waterTankCount;
public Integer getStreetLightCount() {
    return streetLightCount;
}
public void setStreetLightCount(Integer streetLightCount) {
    this.streetLightCount = streetLightCount;
}
public Integer getWaterTankCount() {
    return waterTankCount;
}
public void setWaterTankCount(Integer waterTankCount) {
    this.waterTankCount = waterTankCount;
}
public ResourceCount(Integer streetLightCount, Integer waterTankCount) {
    super();
    this.streetLightCount = streetLightCount;
    this.waterTankCount = waterTankCount;
}
public ResourceCount() {
    super();
}
```

}

Sample code:

```
Map<CityArea, Map<Integer,ResourceCount>> map = new HashMap<>();

    CityArea ca1= new CityArea("cityId1", "1");
    CityArea ca2= new CityArea("cityId1", "2");

    CityArea ca3= new CityArea("cityId2", "1");
    CityArea ca4= new CityArea("cityId2", "2");

    ResourceCount resourceCount1 = new ResourceCount(10, 10);
    ResourceCount resourceCount2 = new ResourceCount(10, 10);

    Map<Integer,ResourceCount> resourceMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    resourceMap1.put(1, resourceCount1);
    resourceMap1.put(2, resourceCount2);

    map.put(ca1, resourceMap1);
    map.put(ca2, resourceMap1);

    Map<Integer,ResourceCount> resourceMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    resourceMap2.put(1, resourceCount1);
    resourceMap2.put(2, resourceCount2);

    map.put(ca3, resourceMap2);
    map.put(ca4, resourceMap2);
```

Input:

```
  {
  CityArea [cityId=cityId2, areaPin=2]=
  {1=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=10, waterTankCount=10],
   2=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=20, waterTankCount=20]},


 CityArea [cityId=cityId1, areaPin=2]=
 {1=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=10, waterTankCount=10],
  2=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=20, waterTankCount=20]}, 

 CityArea [cityId=cityId1, areaPin=1]=
 {1=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=10, waterTankCount=10],
 2=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=20, waterTankCount=20]},

 CityArea [cityId=cityId2, areaPin=1]=
 {1=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=10, waterTankCount=10],
 2=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=20, waterTankCount=20]}

 }
```

Expected Output Map:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, ResourceCount>>

cityId1 = {1=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=20, waterTankCount=20],
            2=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=40, waterTankCount=40]},

cityId2 = {1=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=20, waterTankCount=20],
            2=ResourceCount [streetLightCount=40, waterTankCount=40]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out,

```
final Map<String, Map<Integer, ResourceCount>> destMap = map.entrySet().stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey().getCityId(), Map.Entry::getValue, (resMap1, resMap2) -> {
            return Stream.of(resMap1, resMap2).flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                            (rc1, rc2) -> new ResourceCount(
                                    rc1.getStreetLightCount() + rc2.getStreetLightCount(),
                                    rc1.getWaterTankCount() + rc2.getWaterTankCount())));
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

First define an immediate class to hold your data:

```
public class CityResource {
   String cityId;
   Integer areaPin;
   ResourceCount resource;
   // Constructor, getter, setter
}
```

Then aggregate your data:

```
Map<CityArea, Map<Integer, ResourceCount>> input = ...;

Map<String, Map<Integer, ResourceCount>> output = 
input.entrySet().stream()
     .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().map(r -> new CityResource(e.getKey(), r.getKey(), r.getValue())))
     .collect(groupingBy(CityResource::getCityId, 
                  groupingBy(CityResource::getAreaPin, reducing(new ResourceCount(), (r1, r2) -> new ResourceCount(r1.getStreetLightCount() + r2.getStreetLightCount(), r1.getWaterTankCount() + r2.getWaterTankCount())))));
```

Comment: Do need to add CityArea cityArea or cityId in intermediate class?

Comment: You have to provide getter setter and constructor as I commented in your class